# How can `shared_ptr<SubClass>` be a subclass of `shared_ptr<BaseClass>`?

Tags: c++

> How can `shared_ptr<SubClass>` be a subclass of `shared_ptr<BaseClass>`?

I wonder how to implement a template class `C<T>` such that `C<SubClass>` is a subclass of `C<BaseClass>`?

I've observed the above with, e.g., `shared_ptr<SubClass>` and `shared_ptr<BaseClass>`, where I can  assign the former to the latter.

Comment: Being able to assign `shared_ptr<SubClass>` to `shared_ptr<BaseClass>` doesn't mean they are in a base class/sub class relationship themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `shared_ptr<SubClass>` is not inherited from `shared_ptr<BaseClass>`.

> I've observed the above with, e.g., `shared_ptr<SubClass>` and
>   `shared_ptr<BaseClass>`, where I can assign the former to the latter.

The `shared_ptr<BaseClass>` has such assignment operator `template< class Y > 
shared_ptr& operator=( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;` that does the conversion when `Y` is `SubClass`.